# efficient computation of Trace(AB^{-1}) given A and B

Tags: math, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have two square matrices A and B. A is symmetric, B is symmetric positive definite. I would like to compute $trace(A.B^{-1})$. For now, I compute the Cholesky decomposition of B, solve for C in the equation $A=C.B$ and sum up the diagonal elements.

Is there a more efficient way of proceeding?

I plan on using Eigen. Could you provide an implementation if the matrices are sparse (A can often be diagonal, B is often band-diagonal)?

Comment: I think the C++ tag actually does belong here, since the question is about an implementation using Eigen, a C++ matrix manipulation library.

Comment: Is A positive semidefinite or positive definite?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I removed the tag

Comment: @FooBah A is a sample variance covariance matrix. I'd be tempted to say that it's spd but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's certainly semidefinite if it's a covariance matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `B` is sparse, it may be efficient (i.e., O(n), assuming good condition number of `B`) to solve for `x_i` in

```
B x_i = a_i
```

(sample [Conjugate Gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) code is given on Wikipedia). Taking `a_i` to be the column vectors of `A`, you get the matrix `B^{-1} A` in O(n^2). Then you can sum the diagonal elements to get the trace. Generally, it's easier to do this sparse inverse multiplication than to get the full set of eigenvalues. <del>For comparison, [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) is O(n^3).</del> (*see  Darren Engwirda's comment below about Cholesky*).

If you only need an approximation to the trace, you can actually reduce the cost to O(q n) by averaging

```
r^T (A B^{-1}) r
```

over `q` random vectors `r`. Usually `q << n`. This is an unbiased estimate provided that the components of the random vector `r` satisfy

```
< r_i r_j > = \delta_{ij}
```

where `< ... >` indicates an average over the distribution of `r`. For example, components `r_i` could be independent gaussian distributed with unit variance. Or they could be selected uniformly from +-1. Typically the trace scales like O(n) and the error in the trace estimate scales like O(sqrt(n/q)), so the *relative* error scales as O(sqrt(1/nq)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you do the averaging with r ? from what you write, it seems like you need to compute A.B^{-1} which is probably not what you wanted to say.

Comment: Kipton probably means you should compute r^T A B^{-1} r by first solving B x = r and then computing r^T A x. But I do not see how he gets a cost of O(n) for the probabilistic approach: solving n systems with cost O(n) each gives a cost of O(n^2). Perhaps the number of random vectors can be taken smaller than n = size of A?

Comment: @Kipton Barros: The complexity for a *sparse* Cholesky factorisation is definitely not `O(N^3)` - that would be a dense factorisation, the sparse case is typically much, much faster. Using a `PCG` solver to solve `N` linear systems would result in *at least* `O(N|B|)` complexity, which would only be `O(N^2)` in the case of diagonal `B`. I would probably benchmark against a "good" sparse factorisation package, perhaps `CHOLMOD`.

Comment: @Darren, Thanks for the correction about Cholesky decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

If generalized eigenvalues are more efficient to compute, you can compute the generalized eigenvalues, `A*v = lambda* B *v` and then sum up all the lambdas.